# How to extract the GAV from a pom.xml file in a shell script

Tags: shell, maven

I need to extract the Maven GAV (groupId, artifactId, version) from a large number of `pom.xml` files. Not all of the POMs have a parent POM declaration, so the inheritance between parent GAV and project GAV needs to be taken into account.

I'd only like to use tools that can be easily scripted in a linux shell, e.g. bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
grep -v '\[' <( mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression="project.groupId" 2>/dev/null && 
    mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression="project.artifactId" 2>/dev/null && 
    mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression="project.version" 2>/dev/null )
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: It's not a critique, just a suggestion to make your one-line solver more useful and valuable for future SO users.

Comment: Requires that dependencies are already updated (i.e. no "Downloading"/"Downloaded" messages), but then it works great!

Comment: When Maven executes it provides a great deal of informational standard out. This script works by excluding the informational STDOUT from the Maven output using a grep exclude. (Maven STDOUT contains logging keys, like "[INFO]" that are precluded by the '\'.) Then the only parts left are the actual command output from the Help plugin. (The evaluate goal of the Help plugin simply performs an expression evaluation as provided in the '-Dexpression=' command-line flag.)

Comment: It's actually possible to do this without the `grep` from version 3.1.0 of the maven-help-plugin. It now includes a parameter "forceStdout" which you can use with the maven "-q" switch to print just the result you want. e.g. `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression="project.groupId" -q -DforceStdout`

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I could find is using an XSL transformation. Create a file `extract-gav.xsl` with the following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:pom="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/pom:project">
        <!-- this XML element just serves as a bracket and may be omitted -->
        <xsl:element name="artifact">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

            <!-- process coordinates declared at project and project/parent -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="pom:groupId|pom:parent/pom:groupId" mode="copy-coordinate"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="pom:artifactId|pom:parent/pom:artifactId" mode="copy-coordinate"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="pom:version|pom:parent/pom:version" mode="copy-coordinate"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-coordinate">
        <!-- omit parent coordinate if same coordinate is explicitly specified on project level -->
        <xsl:if test="not(../../*[name(.)=name(current())])">

            <!-- write coordinate as XML element without namespace declarations -->
            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transformation can then be invoked in a shell (assuming that you have the libxslt installed) with th command `xsltproc extract-gav.xsl pom.xml`

This produces the output in the following format:

```xml
<artifact>
  <groupId>org.example.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>example-artifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
</artifact>
```

If you need a different format, the XSL transformation should be easy enough to adapt so that it suits your needs. E.g. the following transformation writes the GAV as tab-separated plain text:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:pom="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/pom:project">
        <!-- process coordinates declared at project and project/parent -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="pom:groupId|pom:parent/pom:groupId" mode="copy-coordinate"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="pom:artifactId|pom:parent/pom:artifactId" mode="copy-coordinate"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="pom:version|pom:parent/pom:version" mode="copy-coordinate"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-coordinate">
        <xsl:if test="not(../../*[name(.)=name(current())])">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a groovy script called **pom** that I placed on PATH. It looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def cli = new CliBuilder(usage:'pom')
cli.h('print usage')
cli.n('do not auto-print output')
cli.p(args:1, argName:'pom', 'the POM file to use')

def options = cli.parse(args)
def arguments = options.arguments()

if (options.h || arguments.size() == 0 ) {
    println cli.usage()
} else {
    def fileName = options.p ? options.p : "pom.xml"
    def script = arguments[0]

    def output = Eval.x(new XmlSlurper().parse(new File(fileName)), "x.${script}")
    if (!options.n) println output
}
```

Now you can extract values like this:

```
pom version
pom groupId
pom 'properties."project.build.sourceEncoding"'
pom -n 'modules.module.each { println it }'
pom -n 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.each { \
    println "${it.groupId}:${it.artifactId}:${it.version}" \
}'
```