# How to extract the artifactId from all pom.xml files using in a multimodule project (using shell script)?

Tags: shell, maven, bamboo

I need to extract the artifactId from all the poms in a multimodule project.

The project structure is similar to this but the structure can be different (It's depends of the project):

```
project
|------->pom.xml
|------->subproject1
            |------->pom.xml
            |------->folder1
                        |------->pom.xml                
|------->subproject2
            |------->pom.xml
            |------->folder2
                        |------->pom.xml                        
|------->subproject3
            |------->pom.xml
            |------->folder3
                        |------->pom.xml                        
|------->subproject4
            |------->pom.xml
            |------->folder4
                        |------->pom.xml
|------->subproject5
            |------->pom.xml
            |------->folder5
                        |------->pom.xml
```

I'm using this command for extract the info in single module projects:

```
MVN_ARTIFACTID=$(mvn -q \
-Dexec.executable="echo" \
-Dexec.args='${project.artifactId}' \
--non-recursive \
org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec)
```

Then I use this variable for other actions in a Bamboo Plan.

How I can do similar tasks with multimodule projects? I need to extract the artifactId of all poms in variables.

I know about this post but It's not the same problem:
[How to extract the GAV from a pom.xml file in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880730/how-to-extract-the-gav-from-a-pom-xml-file-in-a-shell-script)

Thanks.

Comment: Question: Why do you need them? If you have a multi module build all versions should be identical?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post. I only need the artifactId (version and groupId are the same in all modules).   I need the artifactId of all poms because I need to update the archetype-catalog.xml of a repo in Artifactory (using Bamboo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove non recursive option :

```
MVN_ARTIFACTID=$(mvn -q -Dexec.executable="echo" -Dexec.args='${project.artifactId} ##' org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec)
echo $MVN_ARTIFACTID| sed 's/##/\n/g'
```

Added ## as a small hack so that second line can give artifactId names in more readable format. Else all modules will be echoed in same line.

```
Module-1
Module-2
Module-3
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it (adapted from the answer referenced in the question):

```
 grep -v '\[' <( find . -type f -name 'pom.xml' -exec mvn -f{} help:evaluate -Dexpression="project.artifactId" \; )
```

Note that the other answer didn't work for me in Maven 3.5.4.